# Conformal mapping that removes a segment from upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find a conformal mapping that maps the upper half complex plane $\mathbb{H}$ to itself, minus a segment, e.g. $f: \mathbb{H} \to \mathbb{H} - \{(t\cos\alpha, t\sin\alpha) \in \mathbb{C}: 0 < t < b\}$ (for some angle $0 \leq \alpha \leq \pi$).

Graphically, I need to map $\mathbb{H}$ to this:

[image: Transformed UV plane (image)]

Closest question I could find was [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2767722/conformal-mapping), but that's mapping just a strip ($0 < \Im(z) < 1$) instead of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: Your domain can be seen as a degenerate polynomial, so my guess would be that you need a Schwarz-Christoffel mapping.

Comment: I meant a degenerate polygon, not polynomial.